# How can I convince an older person to at least **try** to learn how to use a PC?

Tags: arguments

I have no clue if this is the right forum.

My father who is in his mid 50's basically always asks me to fix things, help him with random IT related things.

It is definitely fine to help, but most of the time, I find the answer in 5 seconds using Google and the first link.

I have shown him that multiple times but he just doesn't care, he just wants it to be fixed, period.

From that, we had a discussion. I was saying that he could make an effort and try to have a basic understanding in order to save time later on.

Of course, I'm just talking about using web surfing, excel and other basic softwares.

My arguments:

- if you understand at least some basics, you will be able to fix 80% your issues and save time from that on the long run
- He could actually use it more for his work and probably be more productive on the long run
- It's not complicated, he is just not interested, and thus doesn't make the effort to be curious, as I believe my father can handle more complicated things than Google searchs.
- He actually manages to handle his Iphone and his IPad quite well, taking pictures, using GPS etc pretty easily. I pointed out that an IPad, for instance, is a computer too and thus he should be able to handle another version of it if he tried. (but he will stay on his position that a tablet is NOT a computer, it's a tablet, period.)
- He could actually save some money because he has a contract with a IT support company. The technicians will mostly fix those random issues in 2 minutes for him.

His arguments:

- Computers are easier for young people and it's way too much complicated for him.
- I work in IT (developer) and thus can't understand "normal" people

It won't change my life that much but it bothers me when I know his life could be much easier.

How can I convince him to at least **try** to learn? in order to demystify the use of a PC.

Comment: Don't make him learn to use a PC, let him learn a Mac. That's what Apple devices are made for - those who need a simple interface. People who don't need to understand why.

Comment: That's already the case. I mean for things like google search, excel etc... just the basics of those.

Comment: Every time you need to fill your car with gas, call him and get him to step you through it.

Comment: is he lonely? maybe he just wants you (his son) around.

Comment: +1 for Mark´s suggestion. Go the Apple route if possible. He sounds as if he is scared of being made to look foolish if something goes wrong. It´s like asking me to dance...

Comment: Using a Mac is no less hard/confusing than using a Windows PC to a person who refuses to learn anything because "computers are hard".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop simply fixing his problems...

Instead of just fixing his issues walk him through fixing them himself, eventually he is bound to learn some basic troubleshooting.  Simply forcing him to type the words into google himself, search for the resolution, and then to perform the resolution will give him the skills required.

hit him up with a Proverb:

give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

-he has probably said this to you in the past

Comment: "Fix a man's computer and he'll bug you for eternity; teach a man to fix his own computer, and he'll forget what you taught him a day later." - President Abe Lincoln

Answer (score 1):

As a computer tech person myself, I have dealth with many people who need a computer but wouldn't if it was up to them.

They really are not interested in fixing the problems, and every time a pc doesn't work, it causes frustration. Having someone like you to fix it reduces this level.

So sure, they will come to you and sure you'll get easy problems and fix them quickly.

For the simple solutions you could show him how you solved it in an attempt to get him to solve that particular problem the next time, but he'll likely call you again even though hey may know the solution.

To motivate him to learn, is making sure you're not available directly. Make him suffer a little bit just so he gets the option: solve it himself = quick, letting you help = slow.

The first few times he'll have to wait. You can even increase the wait time sometimes. And you can try a "on-the-phone" solving thing, where he performs the actions himself. First you can just instruct him what to do, and then later communicate about things like: Hey, I don't have a pc with me right now. Can you go to google and search? use these keywords... What is the first link? And build it up from there.

But even though you might get him to solve things eventually, do note that when people who know little about computers start to try stuff on their own, they usually end up making things a lot worse. Like clicking the wrong buttons getting spyware and stuff.